Pieces not visible when using chessboard.js
After following what the documentation says on chessboardjs.com using the unpkg CDN, the chessboard appears without the pieces. I'm assuming that this is because the library scripts don't know how to find the images, but I don't know how to reconcile this. Here is my code. As you can see, I tried downloading the image files locally, but even this didn't seem to resolve the issue.
├── img
│   └── chesspieces
│       └── wikipedia
├── public
    ├── pages
    ├── scripts
    └── styles



var config = {
  pieceTheme: '/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png',
  position: 'start'
}
var board1 = Chessboard('board1', config);
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/game.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.css" integrity="sha384-q94+BZtLrkL1/ohfjR8c6L+A6qzNH9R2hBLwyoAfu3i/WCvQjzL2RQJ3uNHDISdU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="board1"></div>
<div class="buttons">
  <a href="lobby.html"><button class="button">Exit</button></a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZvpUoO/+PpLXR1lu4jmpXWu80pZlYUAfxl5NsBMWOEPSjUn/6Z/hRTt8+pR6L4N2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha384-8Vi8VHwn3vjQ9eUHUxex3JSN/NFqUg3QbPyX8kWyb93+8AC/pPWTzj+nHtbC5bxD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../scripts/chess.js"></script>




Perhaps pieceTheme: 'img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png', if the image folder is below where your HTML file is? And do you have all the wP.png bP.png etc in that folder?

├───img
│   └───chesspieces
│       └───wikipedia
└───public
├───pages
├───scripts
└───styles
This is the structure of my project. The html and js files I listed in my original post are in the pages and scripts folders respectively. The files you mentioned are in the /img/chesspieces/wikipedia/ folder.

This is the structure of my project put that in the question where you can format it so that it is readable

If the structure is how I pasted in your question, then your img folder needs to be in the public folder. Your root is public and not your home directory.
